# Global application state with FLTK library

Tags: user-interface, rust, fltk

I'm writing an application using the fltk library.
The architecture of the application involves a global state that stores which page to display now (viewer) and store the viewer data.
There are buttons that sends a message to update and changes the global state indicating which viewer to display now.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Message {
    Update
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct GlobalState {
    viewer: Viewer,
}

impl GlobalState {
    fn set_viewer(&mut self, v: Viewer) {
        self.viewer = v;
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Viewer {
    Page1,
    Page2
}

fn main() {
    let mut gs = GlobalState {viewer: Viewer::Page1};

    let app = app::App::default().with_scheme(app::Scheme::Gtk);
    let (s, r) = app::channel::<Message>();
    let mut wind = Window::default().with_size(800, 600);

    left_side(&mut gs);

    let mut col = Column::new(155,70,800 - 150,600 - 65,None);
    s.send(Message::Update);
    col.end();
    wind.end();
    wind.show();

    while app.wait() {
        if let Some(msg) = r.recv() {
            match msg {
                Message::Update => {
                    match gs.viewer {
                        Viewer::Page1 => {
                            col.clear();
                            let view = view_ohm();
                            col.add(&view);
                        },
                        Viewer::Page2 => {
                            col.clear();
                            let view = view_ohm();
                            col.add(&view);
                        },
                        _ => ()
                    }
                }
                _ => (),
            }
        }
    }
}

fn left_side(gs: &mut GlobalState) {
    let btn_width = 130;
    let btn_height = 30;

    let (s, r) = app::channel::<Message>();

    let mut grp = Group::default().with_size(65, 600);
    let mut col = Pack::default()
        .with_size(btn_width, 600)
        .center_of_parent()
        .with_type(PackType::Vertical);
    col.set_spacing(2);

    let mut btn = Button::new(0, 0, btn_width, btn_height, "Page 1");
    btn.emit(s, Message::Update);
    btn.set_callback(|_| {
        gs.set_viewer(Viewer::Page1)
    });

    let mut btn = Button::new(0, 0, btn_width, btn_height, "Page 2");
    btn.emit(s, Message::Update);
    btn.set_callback(|_| {
        gs.set_viewer(Viewer::Page2)
    });

    col.end();
    grp.end();
}
```

Questions:

1. the code doesn't compile with error:

```
    error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
      --> src/main.rs:89:5
       |
    74 |   fn left_side(gs: &mut GlobalState) {
       |                --  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
       |                |
       |                `gs` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
    ...
    89 | /     btn.set_callback(|_| {
    90 | |         gs.set_viewer(Viewer::Page1)
    91 | |     });
       | |      ^
       | |      |
       | |______`gs` escapes the function body here
       |        argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
    
    error[E0524]: two closures require unique access to `*gs` at the same time
      --> src/main.rs:95:22
       |
    89 |       btn.set_callback(|_| {
       |       -                --- first closure is constructed here
       |  _____|
       | |
    90 | |         gs.set_viewer(Viewer::Page1)
       | |         -- first borrow occurs due to use of `*gs` in closure
    91 | |     });
       | |______- argument requires that `*gs` is borrowed for `'static`
    ...
    95 |       btn.set_callback(|_| {
       |                        ^^^ second closure is constructed here
    96 |           gs.set_viewer(Viewer::Page2)
       |           -- second borrow occurs due to use of `*gs` in closure
```

2. my application architecture working or is there a better one? The application has several pages (one page one viewer) and each viewer has its own global state and the data that is stored in it and processes this data.
3. What is the best way to store viewer data in the global state?

Comment: You're using `gs: &mut GlobalState` in multiple closures. Using a reference in a closure essentially places that reference on the closure structure. However, the compiler doesn't allow you to have multiple mutable (unique) references alive at the same time. You'll have to use something like `RefCell` or `Mutex` to allow internal mutability through an immutable (shared) reference.

Comment: I try to use RefCell but the code doesn't work again:
```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct GlobalState {
    viewer: RefCell<Viewer>,
}
impl GlobalState {
    fn set_viewer(&self, v: Viewer) {
        *self.viewer.borrow_mut() = v;
    }
}
fn main() {
    let gs = GlobalState {viewer: RefCell::new(Viewer::Page1)};
....
    left_side(gs);
...
}

fn left_side(gs: GlobalState) {
....
    btn.set_callback(|_| {
        gs.set_viewer(Viewer::Page1)
    });
....
}
```

Comment: Edit the code and the resulting error into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code wraps your GlobalState in an `Rc<RefCell<GlobalState>>`:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Message {
    Update
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct GlobalState {
    viewer: Viewer,
}

impl GlobalState {
    fn set_viewer(&mut self, v: Viewer) {
        self.viewer = v;
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Viewer {
    Page1,
    Page2
}

fn main() {
    let mut gs = Rc::new(RefCell::new(GlobalState {viewer: Viewer::Page1}));

    let app = app::App::default().with_scheme(app::Scheme::Gtk);
    let (s, r) = app::channel::<Message>();
    let mut wind = Window::default().with_size(800, 600);

    left_side(gs.clone());

    let mut col = Column::new(155,70,800 - 150,600 - 65,None);
    col.end();
    wind.end();
    wind.show();

    while app.wait() {
        if let Some(msg) = r.recv() {
            match msg {
                Message::Update => {
                    let gs = gs.borrow();
                    match gs.viewer {
                        Viewer::Page1 => {
                            col.clear();
                            let view = view_ohm();
                            col.add(&view);
                        },
                        Viewer::Page2 => {
                            col.clear();
                            let view = view_ohm();
                            col.add(&view);
                        },
                        _ => ()
                    }
                }
                _ => (),
            }
        }
    }
}

fn left_side(gs: Rc<RefCell<GlobalState>>) {
    let btn_width = 130;
    let btn_height = 30;

    let s = app::Sender::get();

    let mut grp = Group::default().with_size(65, 600);
    let mut col = Pack::default()
        .with_size(btn_width, 600)
        .center_of_parent()
        .with_type(PackType::Vertical);
    col.set_spacing(2);

    let mut btn = Button::new(0, 0, btn_width, btn_height, "Page 1");

    btn.set_callback({
        let gs = gs.clone();
        move |_| {
        gs.borrow_mut().set_viewer(Viewer::Page1);
        s.send(Message::Update);
    }});

    let mut btn = Button::new(0, 0, btn_width, btn_height, "Page 2");

    btn.set_callback(move |_| {
        gs.borrow_mut().set_viewer(Viewer::Page2);
        s.send(Message::Update);
    });

    col.end();
    grp.end();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
The code compiles but doesn't work as expected because the global state doesn't change.
The code inside the 'move' block does not work.
If the year is changed like this:
    btn.set_callback({
        let gs = gs.clone();
        println!("page1_1");
        move |_| {
        println!("page1_2");
            gs.borrow_mut().set_viewer(Viewer::Page1)
    }});
    btn.emit(s, Message::Update);
Then when you run the console will only:
page1_1
page2_1
and when you click on the buttons, nothing else is displayed in the console.

Comment: I've updated the example, emit and set_callback can't be used together since both will just set the callback. You'll need to s.send in the callback